# Know what tables each user is accessing

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, audit

I have a database with a lot of users, all of them with full read privileges on all the tables but not all the users are reading all the tables. I want to have each user having as little privileges as they need. Each user belongs to a different large legacy application for which auditing the code is not feasible.

How do I go about obtaining this information?

Answer (score 2):

This would have a considerable impact on your system, but you could enable the [MySQL General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) by running the following:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

The default setting for the logs will output to a file that can be identified by running this:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'general_log_file';
```

Otherwise, you can change the setting to log in a table with the line below, and then you would be able to run queries on the table `mysql.general_log`

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: What tool do I use then to parse the logs and build the graph?

Comment: One possible tool is your eyeballs.  Another may be `pt-query-digest`.